# How do I enforce total character count in regex?

Tags: javascript, regex

Suppose I have a string of numbers whose length is 4.

```
const example = "1234";
```

I need to verify the following patterns are all valid:

```
1-2-3-4
1234
12-34
1-234
123-4
```

I'm setting my first and last characters to be numbers. So that leaves 3 possible locations for the "-" character. This is what I have right now:

```
\d{1}[-]? (\d[-]?){0,2} [-]?\d{1}
```

This seems to be working correctly. However, it also ends up matching strings like

```
12
```

which doesn't honor the rule of the string being 4 characters long. How do I enforce the total character length here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your pattern would allow `12` because this part `(\d[-]?){0,2}` can match either 0, 1 or 2 times and only the first and the last digits are not optional.

You might use a repeating group with an optional `-`

Note that you might omit the `{1}`

```
^\d(?:-?\d){3}$
```

- `^` Start of string
- `\d` Match a digit
- `(?:-?\d){3}` Repeat 3 times matching an optional `-` and a digit
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/FcjJSF/1)